# Ambari - Topology host info is not cleared when a host is removed

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

When a host is removed, a record is left in the topology_host_info table, topology_host_request table and probably in few others also.

[Ambari JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-15457)

The bad news is that I can't delete old ZooKeeper servers. When I restart ZooKeeper sever using Ambari the old servers are added to ZooKeeper server configuration: /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg and I don't have a quorum, so the whole cluster is down..

The only quick solution for me is to manually delete the old ZooKeeper servers from configuration file and run ZooKeeper server from command line - but this is not solution.

Now I'm stuck .. I can't use Ambari to manage my ZooKeeper Servers,
the old ZooKeepers are in the topology_host_info table, topology_host_request table, and this tables does not contain the new ZooKeeper Servers..

Do you think that Ambari upgrade to 2.2.2 could solve this problem?

Do you have any experience in Ambari server upgrade?

I already knew that I must backup PgSQL database, and I have also read the doc: [HDPDocuments/Ambari](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.0.0/bk_upgrading_Ambari/content/_upgrade_to_ambari_2.1.html) but I just want to ask if you have experienced any problems with the Ambari server upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to 2.2.2 will resolve the issue. As part of the upgrade process the configurations will be amended to account for the issue you experienced and will be corrected.

Ambari server upgrades are well documented on the HDP site and in my experience have not caused any issues.

Comment: Sometimes the upgrade may fail so first check for any errors in ambari-server log and try to resolve them. If the ambari-server upgrade steps fails it's a bit tricky to resolve and bring back the correct state.